# Styling blog headers only

Tags: css, wordpress

I am wondering if there is any way to edit the header of blog post headers only, while retaining the styling for regular page headers?

I can edit page header styling(including blog posts) using:

```
.has-image.listing-cover, .has-image.listing-cover a, .has-image.page-cover{}
```

Is there a way to edit the blog post headers only?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean the header for the blog page or the header for each blog post?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. I mean the header for each blog post

Comment: You'll need to use the body classes to help you correctly target the elements you want to style. Use your web-browsers inspector to check the classes for the body element. I wouldn't suggest using the class .has-image as presumably your targeting will not work if an image is not present. Gonna need more detail to give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's definitely possible. Wordpress adds additional classes to the body depending on the post type of each page.

If you prepend your CSS rules with `body.single-post` it will target only blog posts.

As an example, if you wanted the `.site-header` to have a red background only when a visitor views a blog post, your style would look like this:

```
body.single-post .siteheader {
  background-color:red;
}
```

To use your example:

```
.has-image.listing-cover, 
.has-image.listing-cover a, 
.has-image.page-cover { 
    /*Your CSS Rules Here*/
}
```

would become:

```
body.single-post .has-image.listing-cover, 
body.single-post .has-image.listing-cover a, 
body.single-post .has-image.page-cover { 
    /*Your CSS Rules Here*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you sou much for your advice. That worked perfectly! Many thanks